# Simple react functional component not generating HTML

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out the best ways of creating functional components that generate simple html - take this nav-links.js file for example:

```
export const navLinks = [
  {
    name: "home",
    href: "/"
  },
  {
    name: "subs",
    href: "/subs"
  }
];
```

The html my component attempts to generate just loops through each link to generate an unordered-list with list tags and a tags inside.

The problem occurs in this nav-menu.js file, where the output is just an two `<ul></ul>` tags with nothing inside:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import {navLinks} from "../util/nav-links";

export const NavMenu = () => {
  const lis = () => (
    {navLinks}.map(link => {
      return (
        <li>
          <Link to={link.href} key={link.href}>{link.name}</Link>
        </li>
      )
    })
  )

  return (
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
          {lis}
        </ul>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Why is nothing rendering in the above component? I wrote some more code below that solves it, although I wonder whether it could be refactored better:

```
export const NavMenu = () => {
    return (
      <div id="navbar">
          <ul>
            {navLinks.map(link => {
              return (
                <li>
                  <Link to={link.href} key={link.href}>{link.name}</Link>
                </li>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
    )
  }
```

Why does the first attempt not work, and how could it be better refactored? Thanks for any help here

Comment: What happens if instead of `{lis}` you use `{lis()}` or rename it to `Lis` (capital letter) and try `<Lis />`?

Comment: It didn't work first time, because you attempted to use `Array.prototype.map()` on `Object` (since you destructured your `navLInks` array into `navLinks` variable when you did `import {navLinks} from "../util/nav-links"`, and then created an object `{navLinks: [{name: 'home', href: '/'},{name: 'subs', href: '/subs'}]}` when you wrapped `navLinks` into curly braces). So your first attempt, most probably, threw an error. It would work as expected if you skipped curly braces: `navLInks.map(..`. Though, I would prefer second approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your the first example didn't work because you passed the `const list = () => {..}` as a anonymous function without calling it, inside the curly braces in the JSX portion of you code.

If you have called it like `{list()}`:

```
return (
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
          {lis()}
        </ul>
    </div>
)
```

This way it would have probably worked.

Or you could have stored the list inside a variable like this:

```
const lis = navLinks.map(link => {
      return (
        <li>
          <Link to={link.href} key={link.href}>{link.name}</Link>
        </li>
      )
    }
)
```

or also like this:

```
const lis = navLinks.map(link => (
        <li>
          <Link to={link.href} key={link.href}>{link.name}</Link>
        </li>
      )
    )
)
```